# локальный файловый сервер

Tags: c#

хочу попытаться реализовать десктопный локальный сервер файлообменник в радиусе одного сети, аналог почтового веб сервера, чтобы отправлять файлы (документы ) и получать на той стороне машины. в гитхабе много исходников с реализаций соккетом, в таком случае нужно чтобы отправитель и получатель был в онлайн режиме ( подключен в режиме онлайн к сети ). есть ли такой вариант чтоб через сервер это реализовать и желательно на c#?

Comment: Почему бы просто не пошарить папку по сети? В Windows есть нормальный общий доступ к папкам. Да и других готовых решений для файловых помоек немеряно.

Comment: @aepot ,  ну хочется сделать такой компактный десктопный вариант дополнительным интерфейсом если получится еще и локальный сервак пристроит чтоб пользователи  через сервер обращались друг другу будет вообще супер,

Comment: Ничего не понял, что вы пробовали из существующих инструментов и что именно не устроило? Дополните вопрос.

Comment: существует локальная сеть предприятия количеством 100 человек .  есть необходимость организовать отправку файлов между участниками без доступа к интернету.  есть много исходников, все они работают по принципу  - отправитель и получатель должен быть в сети, и  подключен. а как реализовать вот типа такое (  Mozilla Thunderbird + локальный сервер типа hMailServer ) ? . для каждого  ПК сделать статистический IP, под IP подкрепить какое-то имя, домен . по протоколу SMTP

Comment: Глупости говорите, при совершенно любом раскладе никаких статических IP не надо. Почта безо всяких костылей может работать, можно XMPP чат поднять, клиентов и серверов навалом готовых, передачу файлов протокол вроде поддерживает. Есть платные сервисы типа MS Teams в составе корпоративной системы с AD. В общем, готовых решений много, главное поискать. Писать код здесь не требуется, совсем.

Comment: @aepot вот об этом и хотел узнать , благодарю !